# When extending a class and using properties of original class what do you put inside of super()

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, prototype

This is how I thought the code should work but it doesn't pass.

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(w, h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
    return(this.w * this.h)
}

class Square extends Rectangle{
    constructor(w, h) {
        super(w, h)
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
     }
}
```

I thought that when using super to receive parameters from original class you need to put them in the new constructor?
But when I change class Square like this it passes.  I don't understand?

```
class Square extends Rectangle{
    constructor(s) {
        super(s)
        this.w = s;
        this.h = s;
     }
```

Comment: It's unclear what "it passes" refers to. Do you have an assignment with tests? What do these tests check for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments that the parent constructor expects, in your case you will need to pass a height and a width. How to get these values is up to you. For a square, it makes sense to pass the same value for both parameters. You do no need to assign `.w` and `.h` yourself in the `Square` constructor, the `Rectangle` constructor already creates these properties. So it just be just

```
class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(s) {
        super(s, s)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so if it was a rectangle I would then need to pass it two parameters ex. constructor(w, h) { super(w, h) }

Comment: @Turtle_Pie How many parameters the `Square` constructor takes is your call. But yes, the `super(…, …)` call to `Rectangle` needs two arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!